# Why do we need Urysohn's lemma to "top off" semi-continuous functions?

Tags: general-topology

I was reading Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis," p. 39, which states in part:

"Suppose $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, $V$ is open in $X$, $K\subset V$, and $K$ is compact. Then there exists an $f \in C(X)$ such that $K\subset supp(f) \subset V$."

It goes on to say that "it is easy to find semi-continuous functions that do this," but finding a "qualifying" continuous function is non trivial. Then it introduces Urysohn's lemma as the solution.

Why is this (that is, semi-continuous functions make the problem easy, but continuous functions make it hard)?

Comment: I suppposed $K\subset supp(f) \subset V$ or is it $1_K\leq f\leq 1_V$ ? ($1_K\, 1_V$ being the corresponding characteristic functions). Please re-read carefully Rudin (I don't have mine at hand) and tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want an (upper) semicontinuous function $f$, you can simply define $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in K$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X\setminus K$.  This is upper semicontinous because $K$ is closed.  On the other hand, it will not be continuous unless $K$ is also open, which is usually not the case.  So this very easy construction works if you just want a semicontinuous function, but getting a continuous function requires more work.